# how to pass in external lib jars into java main class?

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, cloudera-cdh

For example I have two different main classes in one application, so I wrote another main class to allow user to choose a main class for invocation, which works fine.

However, for one of the main classes, we need to pass in an external -libjars parameter. This is where my problem is. Because I'm calling the application from another application, I'm unable to pass the parameter. Do you know how I could pass the additional parameter to JVM depending on the user preference.

For example:

Main Application:

Select a application:

1) app 1 
2) app 2

we don't need to pass in additional parameter for app 1 so it Okay but for app two we need to pass in -libjar /../../some.jar (This parameter is not used within the application, it's for the cluster JVM )

How do i do this?

If i was going to invoke those two apps individually then I would do this:

for app1:

yarn jar test.jar app1Main

for app 2:

yarn jar test.jar app2Main -libjars /../../some.jar

Comment: A java invocatio mechanism should be able to distinguish between options for java (JVM) and the program's parameters. For Sun/Oracle's java it is: all options precede classname or -jar jarname; program parameters follow. I'd be surprised if there isn't a similar rule for your yarn.

Comment: Thank you laune for your response. I tried all possiable way but none worked. I decided to bundle up all dependency libs with the app to resolve the issue!